# No puedo ver ni descargar paquetes de nuget en la red. No se puede establecer una relación de confianza para el canal seguro SSL/TLS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy empezando a usar VS2019 en el trabajo. Habia hecho pruebas en casa y el administrador de paquetes siempre me ha funcionado correctamente.

Ahora tengo el siguiente error:

```
[nuget.org] No se puede cargar el índice de servicio del origen https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  Error al enviar la solicitud.
  Se ha terminado la conexión: No se puede establecer una relación de confianza para el canal seguro SSL/TLS.
  El certificado remoto no es válido según el procedimiento de validación.
```

He intentado diversas soluciones:

- deshabilitar el TLS1.3
- deshabilitar los proxys
- instalar el certificado

Ahora mismo, a pesar de haber instalado el certificado, cuando intento acceder a "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" desde internet explorer me salta error de certificado.

Ya no se que solucion más probar.

Si alguien tiene una idea de lo que puede estar pasando agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

pd: he llegado a instalar paquetes offline, pero cuando busco paquetes con muchas subdescargas tengo que buscar uno por uno los paquetes relacionados.

Comment: tenes la computadora con la fecha actual?

Comment: Si, el PC Tiene la fecha actual. És un W10 Versión 20H2

Comment: Estas en una pc tuya o del laburo?

Comment: En mi oficina me pasa lo mismo.. y pienso que es un problema porque hay un proxy y un MITM...

Comment: Es el PC del trabajo. Pero desactivamos el proxy y sigue fallando igual.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUCIONADO:**

Habia instalado el certificado "Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 01" anteriormente pero no funcionaba.

Hoy me he dado cuenta de que la ruta de certificación también fallaba el certificado:
"DigiCert Global Root G2"

Para instalarlos de forma sencilla:

- Abrir internet Explorer i buscar la ruta: "nuget.org"
- Sale "Este sitio no és seguro", seleccionar continuar de todos modos.
- Boton derecho sobre el nombre de la pagina>ver certificados>Ruta de certificacion
- Seleccionar los certificados no verificados>ver certificado.
- En la ventana que se abre seleccionar el boton: "Instalar certificado..."
- Yo lo he instalado en el equipo local y dentro de la carpeta entidades de certificacion de confianza, pero no sé si hay una opción mejor.

Saludos.